# Django Flowbite dropdown doesn't work when I'm looping it in template for loop

Tags: django, django-templates

`Fowbite dropdown` works when I write it out of `for loop`, but when I'm moving it into the `for loop` it stops working. And reason is not html `id`. I wrote 3 `dropdowns` out of `for loop` with same id and it worked.

```
{% for comment in comments %}
                        <div>
                            <button id="dropdown-comments-{{ comment.id }}" data-dropdown-toggle="comment-options-{{ comment.id }}" class="text-primary-900">
                                <i class="w-6 h-6 fa-solid fa-ellipsis-vertical hidden sm:block"></i>
                                <i class="w-6 h-6 fa-solid fa-ellipsis sm:hidden"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
        
                        <div id="comment-options-{{ comment.id }}" class="z-10 hidden bg-white divide-y divide-primary-100 rounded-lg shadow w-44 dark:bg-primary-700">
                            <ul class="py-2 text-sm text-primary-700 dark:text-primary-200" aria-labelledby="comment-options-button">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="" class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-primary-100 dark:hover:bg-primary-600 dark:hover:text-white">
                                        <i class="fa-solid fa-pen mr-3"></i> {% trans "Edit" %}
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <button data-modal-toggle="delete-confirm-{{ comment.id }}" class="block text-start text-red-600 w-full px-4 py-2 hover:bg-primary-100 dark:hover:bg-primary-600 dark:hover:text-white">
                                        <i class="fa-solid fa-trash  mr-3"></i> {% trans "Delete" %}
                                    </button>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
{% endfor %}
```